# Trying to Make My Own Windows 10 De-bloat Script

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, script, sysprep

I'm trying to make my own de-bloat script that will remove both provisioned and user apps from Windows 10. I've made a list of the provisioned apps using this command `Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -Online | Select DisplayName` and filtered it out to show the displayname of each app. In the code below I'm trying to place each listed app into the command below so that I have got to write it out multiple times. Could someone explain where I'm going wrong please?

P.S I'm extremely new to PowerShell.

```
# This script de-bloats unwanted apps from Windows 10.
# To keep certain apps insert a '#' at the beginning of the line 
# and it will be skipped from being removed. 

Write-Output "Uninstalling provisioned apps"
$ProvisionedApps = @(
    "Microsoft.BingWeather"
    #"Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller"
    "Microsoft.GetHelp"
    "Microsoft.Getstarted"
    #"Microsoft.HEIFImageExtension"
    "Microsoft.Messaging"
    "Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer"
    "Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub"
    "Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection"
    #"Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes"
    "Microsoft.MixedReality.Portal"
    #"Microsoft.MSPaint"
    #"Microsoft.Office.OneNote"
    "Microsoft.OneConnect"
    "Microsoft.People"
    "Microsoft.Print3D"
    "Microsoft.ScreenSketch"
    #"Microsoft.SkypeApp"
    #"Microsoft.StorePurchaseApp"
    #"Microsoft.VP9VideoExtensions"
    "Microsoft.Wallet"
    #"Microsoft.WebMediaExtensions"
    #"Microsoft.WebpImageExtension"
    #"Microsoft.Windows.Photos"
    #"Microsoft.WindowsAlarms"
    #"Microsoft.WindowsCalculator"
    #"Microsoft.WindowsCamera"
    "microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps"
    "Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub"
    #"Microsoft.WindowsMaps"
    #"Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder"
    #"Microsoft.WindowsStore"
    "Microsoft.Xbox.TCUI"
    "Microsoft.XboxApp"
    "Microsoft.XboxGameOverlay"
    "Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay"
    "Microsoft.XboxIdentityProvider"
    "Microsoft.XboxSpeechToTextOverlay"
    "Microsoft.YourPhone"
    "Microsoft.ZuneMusic"
    "Microsoft.ZuneVideo"
)

foreach ($app in $ProvisionedApps) {
    Write-Output "REMOVING $app"

    Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -Online | Where-Object DisplayName -EQ $ProvisionedApps | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online
}
```

Many thanks

Will

Comment: Welcome. What error are you getting? Please make your title reflect your question/problem.

Comment: Your `Where-Object` compares with the whole collection instead of the currently iterated `$app`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consult the detailed debloating PowerShell script at
[Windows10-Unbloating-v1.ps1](https://gist.github.com/mrik23/e8160517b19a3a9dad9c1b5e8ba0fb78).

The actual code used (I changed variable names to yours) is:

```
foreach ($app in $ProvisionedApps) {
    Get-AppxPackage -Name $app -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
    Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -Online | Where-Object DisplayName -EQ $app | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online
}
```

You will notice in the `Get-AppXProvisionedPackage` command the use of the
`$app` variable instead of `$ProvisionedApps`.